# Shorten if else statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

How can I shorten that if else statement?

```
const isPathPointAvailable = (requiredItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][], oneOfItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][]) => {
    if(requiredItems && requiredItems.length > 0){
        return userHaveMultipleRequiredItems(requiredItems);
    }
    if(oneOfItems && oneOfItems.length > 0){
        return userHaveRequiredItem(oneOfItems);
    }
    return true
```

I tried this but it always return true

```
const isPathPointAvailable = (requiredItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][], oneOfItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][]) => {
    requiredItems && requiredItems.length > 0 && userHaveMultipleRequiredItems(requiredItems);
    oneOfItems && oneOfItems.length > 0 && userHaveRequiredItem(oneOfItems);
    return true
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't change something that works and is perfectly readable. You could write `return requiredItems && requiredItems.length > 0 ? userHaveMultipleRequiredItems(requiredItems) : (oneOfItems && oneOfItems.length > 0 ? userHaveRequiredItem(oneOfItems) : true);` but how is that any better?

Comment: It always returns `true` because you *return true*. You are not using your variables at all, as you are not storing the result of your conditions anywhere.

Comment: I agree with @FelixKling the first code is much better than the second code. If you change the second to work  you'd literally save exactly *four* character. For the entire function. Two characters per `if` statement. You can save two characters with the first code by just omitting the `{` and `}` from the `if` bodies. That's discarding the whitespace but you can also already do that. I see no value of writing worse code that is *factually more confusing* - you couldn't even write it correctly right now. The two saved characters aren't even a worthwhile - just minimise your code for more.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` to return the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) `undefined` if the arrays are not defined.  `length === 0` is also falsy.

```js
const isPathPointAvailable = (requiredItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][], oneOfItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][]) => {
    if(requiredItems?.length) return userHaveMultipleRequiredItems(requiredItems);
    if(oneOfItems?.length) return userHaveRequiredItem(oneOfItems);
    return true
```

You were on the right track with your second attempt, but it is missing the return statements in the shortened ifs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use a simple lambda to refactor those two longer checks with something like:

```
let hasElements = (arr) => arr && arr.length > 0;

const isPathPointAvailable = (requiredItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][], oneOfItems?: ModelTypes['Item'][]) => {
  if( hasElements(requiredItems) ) return userHaveMultipleRequiredItems(requiredItems);
  
  if( hasElements(oneOfItems) ) return userHaveRequiredItem(oneOfItems);
  
  return true
}
```